# Timeout simulation not working with testing-library and useFakeTimers

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, settimeout, testing-library, usefaketimers

I'm working on a vueJS component that allows to display a modal after 5 seconds. the component works well as expected.

```
<template>
    <vue-modal v-if="showModal" data-testid="modal-testid" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "TimeoutExample",
    data() {
        return {
          showModal: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        setTimeout(() => this.displayModal(), 5000)
    },
    methods: {
        displayModal: function() {
            this.showModal = true;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

I implemented the unit tests using jest, testing-library and I wanted to use jest.useFakeTimers to simulate the timeout, but the test is KO.

```
// testing file
describe.only('Vue Component (mobile) 2', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      isMobile.mockImplementation(() => true)
    })

    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.useFakeTimers()
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()
      jest.useRealTimers()
    })

    it('should render title after `props.delay` milliseconds', () => {
      const { queryByTestId } = myRender({
        localVue: myMakeLocalVue(),
      })

      jest.advanceTimersByTime(5001)

      expect(queryByTestId('modal-testid')).toBeVisible()
    })
})
```

do you have any idea how i can test this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me after calling `advanceTimersByTime` inside `waitFor`.

```
describe.only('Vue Component (mobile) 2', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      isMobile.mockImplementation(() => true)
    })

    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.useFakeTimers()
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()
      jest.useRealTimers()
    })

    it('should render title after `props.delay` milliseconds', async () => {
      const { queryByTestId } = myRender({
        localVue: myMakeLocalVue(),
      })

      await waitFor(() => {
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(5001)
      })

      expect(queryByTestId('modal-testid')).toBeVisible()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove this `jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout')`. jest will do it's own magic with for this with `useFakeTimers`
2. I suppose you can not use `async` and `done` callback in one test case. Which version of jest do you use?
3. Add `await localVue.$nextTick()` after `advanceTimersByTime` to wait until Vue apply all the changes

Comment: my bad, I used `async ` and `done` when I started using setTimeout for my tests, now i don't use them anymore. Andnd ok for `spyOn` but it changes nothing

Comment: @Mahmoud I updated the answer. If it does not help add you `myRender` implementation to the question.

Comment: thx @andrey-nelubin for the idea, finally it works after calling `advanceTimersByTime` inside `waitFor`